# Rust pyo3: Any way to pass argument to pyfunction by reference?

Tags: rust, pyo3

```
fn gen_data<'py> (py: Python<'py>, a: Vec<u8>, b: Vec<u8>) -> PyResult<&'py PyBytes>{
    let dp = MyDataStruct {
        data: Bytes::from(a),
        extra_info: Bytes::from(b),
    };
    Ok(PyBytes::new(py, &bincode::serialize(&dp).unwrap()[..]))
}
```

This is a piece of my code, it works of course. But it's unbearable in terms of speed. My suspicion is that copying process make it slow.
On my machine, I convert 5120x 5120 matrix to bytes through numpy and pass to it, which takes 3s to finish the jobs. Since my server is pretty good I don't expect quite a long time for this kind of jobs

This is my datastruct definition.

```
pub struct MyDataStruct {
    pub data: bytes::Bytes,
    pub extra_info: bytes::Bytes,
}
```

Comment: Always worth asking, are you compiling your Rust code with `--release`?

Comment: @loganfsmyth lol, sadly yes

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you would like passed by reference. Is it the `a` and `b` parameters? In that case, acccording to the pyo3 documentation and assuming the input is `bytes` on the python side, you can use `&[u8]`. If the input is `list` then there's no other way but to convert it, since otherwise it'd be a `&[&PyAny]` or something like that, which wouldn't exactly be more helpful. Unless you use rust-numpy, possibly.

Comment: Alternatively if your input is numpy arrays you may want to look at rust-numpy, which probably provides bindings & cheap conversions for numpy types. That would be cheaper than having to convert numpy arrays to full-blown python iterables (or even collections) then to vectors.

Comment: Maybe your method should get [`&PyList`](https://docs.rs/pyo3/0.13.2/pyo3/types/struct.PyList.html) instead of `Vec<u8>`

Comment: @Masklinn &[u8] looks great but it won't compile, after I add static to the type as it requests, it gives me `error[E0597]: `pool` does not live long enough`.

Comment: if you're passing numpy arrays, you could probably use [`PyReadonlyArray`](https://docs.rs/numpy/0.13.1/numpy/struct.PyReadonlyArray.html) from the [numpy crate](https://crates.io/crates/numpy) to avoid copying.

Comment: @kmdreko a great tool, but in the end I need to transfer these data through zmq, so maybe numpy-rust is not that suitable.